# Call WP Rest-Api to GET /users/me returned NOTHING in console

Tags: php, users, login, rest-api

I am trying to get the login details of my wordpress account via WP Rest-Api with Cookies Auth in the logged-in wordpress condition. However, when I run it through a web browser I do not get anything with the http 200 response. I expect to get something on my console. Maybe something is wrong with my code? or I don't get authorization cookies?

This is my PHP script

```
<?php

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', '/var/www/html/mine/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');

do_action( 'plugins_loaded' );

add_action( 'set_logged_in_cookie', 'my_update_cookie' );
function my_update_cookie( $logged_in_cookie ){
    $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE] = $logged_in_cookie;
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue the script which makes the AJAX call to /wp-json/my-plugin/v1/foo.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api', 'my-script.js', [ 'jquery' ] );
    
    // Register custom variables for the AJAX script.
    wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'wpApiSettings', array(
        'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
    ) );
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Ajax script

```
$.ajax( {
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/users/me',
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
    },
    data:{
        'title' : 'Hello Moon'
    }
} ).done( function ( response ) {
    console.log( response );
} );
```

[image: In my console, Nothing printed]

Please help me Master

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You should be sending a GET request to _get_ data.

Comment: You should also look at the 'Network' tab to see the raw request and response from the server.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I've tried using a GET request, but it produces the same results

Comment: @Rup In my 'Network' tab, I'm NOTHING see also result for XHR data transfer

Comment: The network tab normally only records if it's open first, so open your debug tools and reload the page if you haven't tried it already. But it you don't see anything there then still then you're not making the request.

Comment: Ok @Rup, thanks for your answer, it's solved